# Is there any documentation on how to break lines in Jenkins Pipeline declarative code?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Let's say I have such pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                git credentialsId: 'long-cred-name', branch: 'long-branch-name', url: 'https://abc-long-long-url-long-long.com/blabla.git'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to break the longest line. How should it be done?

This made me wonder if there are any consistent rules about how to break lines in such cases. And if so, where can I find them?

I came up with this:

```
git
    credentialsId: 'long-cred-name', 
    branch: 'long-branch-name',
    url: 'https://abc-long-long-url-long-long.com/blabla.git'
```

but this didn't work. However this:

```
git credentialsId: 'long-cred-name',
    branch: 'long-branch-name',
    url: 'https://abc-long-long-url-long-long.com/blabla.git'
```

worked just fine.

I couldn't find any rules about how to break lines in Pipeline code, so I asked ChatGPT, and after few tries I got an answer, that you can also break lines in single method like this:

```
git (
    credentialsId: 'long-cred-name',
    branch: 'long-branch-name',
    url: 'https://abc-long-long-url-long-long.com/blabla.git'
)
```

and indeed this worked too.